# Activity.GetMentions() causes Stack Overflow exception

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

I upgraded Microsoft.Bot.Builder from version 3.5.5 to 3.8.0

Now when I call `GetMentions()` for the activity object I get a System.StackOverflowException from Microsoft.Bot.Connector.dll

Can anyone suggest a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has already been logged in the BotBuilder github repo with consistent repro steps. You can track and subscribe to the issue [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2753).

> Methods `HasContent` and `GetMentions` of `IMessageActivity` cause `StackOverflowException`, because *"An extension method with the same name and signature as an instance method will not be called."* In other words, the extensions methods (with the same name) are never called. Instead the method call gets stuck in a loop.

Looks like the only solution meanwhile, is to downgrade your version.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the extension method directly:

```
ActivityExtensions.HasContent(activity);
```

This issue will be fixed soon, and a new release will be made available.

---

Edit:

3.8.1 has a fix for this issue: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/